# Howto get data through http request for auto search in Angular?

Tags: ajax, angular, httprequest

Hi I am developing web application in Angular JS 5. I am trying to complete auto search feature. I am able to make it work with static values. Now I am trying to get data from making API call. Below is my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { TypeaheadMatch } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';


    @Component({
      selector: 'demo-typeahead-async',
      templateUrl: './async.html'
    })
    export class DemoTypeaheadAsyncComponent {
      asyncSelected: string;
      typeaheadLoading: boolean;
      typeaheadNoResults: boolean;
      dataSource: Observable<any>;
      statesComplex: any[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Alabama', region: 'South' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Alaska', region: 'West' },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Arizona',
          region: 'West'
        },
        { id: 4, name: 'Arkansas', region: 'South' },
        { id: 5, name: 'California', region: 'West' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Colorado', region: 'West' }
    ];

      constructor() {
        this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
          // Runs on every search
          observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
        }).mergeMap((token: string) => this.getStatesAsObservable(token));
      }

      getStatesAsObservable(token: string): Observable<any> {
        let query = new RegExp(token, 'ig');

        return Observable.of(
          this.statesComplex.filter((state: any) => {
            return query.test(state.name);
          })
        );
      }

      changeTypeaheadLoading(e: boolean): void {
        this.typeaheadLoading = e;
      }

      changeTypeaheadNoResults(e: boolean): void {
        this.typeaheadNoResults = e;
      }

      typeaheadOnSelect(e: TypeaheadMatch): void {
        console.log('Selected value: ', e.value);
      }
    }
```

In the above code, I am playing through  this.statesComplex(Hard coded data). 
Below is my html code.

```
<pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
  <input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
         [typeahead]="dataSource"
         (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
         (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
         (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
         [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
         typeaheadOptionField="name"
         placeholder="Locations loaded with timeout"
         class="form-control">
  <div *ngIf="typeaheadLoading===true">Loading</div>
  <div *ngIf="typeaheadNoResults===true">&#10060; No Results Found</div>
```

I have created service to call API as below.

```
this.useronboardService.searchUsers(query).subscribe(results => this.filterUsername(query, results), error => this.onUsersSearchDataLoadFailed(error));
```

I tried as below. Below code did not work for me.

```
 getStatesAsObservable(token: string): Observable<any> {
        let query = new RegExp(token, '');
        return Observable.of(
            this.useronboardService.searchUsers(token).subscribe(
                 result => result.filter((user: any) => {
                   return query.test(user.userName),
                        error => console.log(error)
                }))
    );
```

I want to use above service data instead of this.statesComplex. My service returns array which hold properties id and username. can someone help me to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: You can subscribe to valueChanges Observable of the formControl, add some debounceTime so that it doesn't make a lot of backend calls. And make you backend calls after the debounceTime in the subscribe.

Comment: Thanks pavan. Can you share me few links to get it done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.useronboardService.searchUsers(token)` is already an observable, so you don't need to wrap it in `Observable.of(...)`. Just map the result to filtered values.

```
getStatesAsObservable(token: string): Observable<any> {
    let query = new RegExp(token, '');
    return this.useronboardService.searchUsers(token)
        .map(result => result.filter((user: any) => query.test(user.userName)));
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also you can simplify your constructor, using `Observable.of(this.asyncSelected)` instead of `Observable.create(...)`.

Comment: Hi David. I found one error in above code. If there are two matching records exists as we enter string for search, In ui we will get only one result.